# Java Equivalent to Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, java, dictionary, hash

I am a long time user of Python and really like the way that the dictionaries are used. They are very intuitive and easy to use. Is there a good Java equivalent to python's dictionaries? I have heard of people using hashmaps and hashtables. Could someone explain the similarities and differences of using hashtables and hashmaps versus python's dictionaries?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Python's `dict` class is an implementation of what the Python documentation informally calls "[mapping types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)".  Internally, `dict` is implemented using a hashtable.

Java's [`HashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) class is an implementation of the [`Map`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface.  Internally, `HashMap` is implemented using a hashtable.

There are a few minor differences in syntax, and I believe the implementations are tuned slightly differently, but overall they are completely interchangeable.

Comment: No example provided :(

Comment: @kami: What kind of example would you want?

Comment: Any example that illustrates a java equivalent of python's dictionary in action. A useful answer include some example because most people come here to see examples and use them in their code.

Comment: @kami: I don't think that's right. The question doesn't ask "what is the equivalent Java code for some specific Python code". In fact the question doesn't contain any code at all. I'm not sure what the value would be of adding examples of using the Map API in Java; this answer already links to the canonical documentation. If you want to learn Java, start with a tutorial, not Stack Overflow. I certainly don't think this answer warrants a downvote just because it lacks a copy-pasteable code sample.

Comment: Sad to read that comment saying "most people come here to see examples and *use them in their code*", I hope this is wrong.

Comment: @0xc0de unfortunately most people really do just copy and paste.

Comment: Regardless of whether people want to copy-paste, an example usually helps in understanding anything better, in conversations in general, and programming. in particular. The number of upvotes on this answer is an indication of the level of interest among a population much larger than just the OP. But I do agree it doesn't warrant a downvote

Answer (score 50):

The idea of dictionary and Map is similar. Both contain elements like

```sh
key1:value1, key2:value2 ... and so on
```

In Java, `Map` is implemented different ways like `HashMap`, or `TreeMap` etc. `put(), get()` operations are similar

```
import java.util.HashMap;

Map map = new HashMap();
// Put elements to the map
map.put("Ram", new Double(3434.34));
map.put("Krishna", new Double(123.22));
map.put("Hary", new Double(1378.00));
//to get elements
map.get("Krishna"); // =123.22
map.get("Hary"); // = 1378.00
```

See documentation of HashMap in java8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Comments in Java are `//`, not `#` :)

Answer (score 6):

One difference between the two is that `dict` has stricter requirements as to what data types can act as a key.  Java will allow any object to work as a key -- although you should take care to ensure that the object's `hashCode()` method returns a unique value that reflects its internal state.  Python requires keys to fit its definition of [hashable](http://docs.python.org/3.1/glossary.html#term-hashable), which specifies that the object's hash code should never change over its lifetime.

Comment: This is true, but it's not actually enforced by either language.  Obviously in either a Java `hashCode()` method or in a Python `__hash__()` method, you should try to return a unique value that reflects internal state.  In either Java or Python, if you have a mutable object, it probably shouldn't be a hashtable key, so it makes sense to throw an exception from the `hashCode()` or `__hash__()` methods.

Comment: In my experience, almost anything in Python can be a dict key ... what's the 'stricter requirement'?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware (I don't actually use java) dictionaries are just another name for a hashmap/hashtable.

Grabbing code from [http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/HashMaps/](https://web.archive.org/web/20190311045206/http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/HashMaps/) it seems they are used in a very similar manner, with a bit of extra java boiler-plate.

Comment: Java even has a Dictionary interface which is implemented by Hashtable. HashMap is generally preferred, though.

Comment: @Michael Myers : Dictionary is deprecated, Oracle recommends to use Map instead http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html