# How do you create a dictionary in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, key-value

I am trying to implement a dictionary (as in the physical book). I have a list of words and their meanings.

What data structure / type does Java provide to store a list of words and their meanings as key/value pairs.

How, given a key, can I find and return the value?

Comment: Well, in the spirit of focusing on the question, not the user, I'm voting to reopen. I'm sure this user has finished the course by now anyway. ;) It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540673/java-equivalent-to-python-dictionaries, but I think the answers here are better.

Answer (score 375):

You'll want a `Map<String, String>`. Classes that implement the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface include (but are not limited to):

- [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)
- [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)
- [`Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Each is designed/optimized for certain situations (go to their respective docs for more info). `HashMap` is probably the most common; the go-to default.

For example (using a `HashMap`):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("dog", "type of animal");
System.out.println(map.get("dog"));
```

```
type of animal
```

Comment: @Cruncher It also implements `Map` (check the javadoc)

Comment: @arshajii i have a doubt we manually map all the strings in the dictionary or i can say that we manually storing the meaning of all words. So my question is, is there any way like db (dump) files of dictionary to fetch the words and their meaning/definition so we can avoid adding the meaning of each word manually

Comment: @VighaneshGursale You will need to use a put method to build your data structure during exeuction. Think of a put command as reading the file from disc, and placing it in memory(ram) so you can work with it. If you have a file you want loaded in as a data structure on load auto you wouuld need to look into java spring but its complex.

Comment: By the way, you actually don't need to include <String, String> the second time.  You can just do `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: You forgot to mention ConcurrentHashMap which more preferable to use over Hashtable

Comment: To save you the lookup - "The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls." - Taken from the link in the answer - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 100):

This creates dictionary of text (string):

```java
Map<String, String> dictionary = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

you then use it as a:

```java
dictionary.put("key", "value");
String value = dictionary.get("key");
```

> Works but gives an error you need to keep the constructor class same as the declaration class. I know it inherits from the parent class but, unfortunately it gives an error on runtime.

```java
Map<String, String> dictionary = new Map<String, String>();
```

This works properly.

Comment: True, probably some C# slipped in :)

Answer (score 11):

Use [Map interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and an implementation like [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 9):

There's an Abstract Class Dictionary

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html

However this requires implementation.

Java gives us a nice implementation called a Hashtable

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Comment: `Dictionary` is obsoleted and none of the implementations extend it.

Comment: @asgs what does that mean? I still can use it in Java 11 though? (sorry I am not very familiar with Java)

Comment: @cryanbhu Dictionary is [deprecated in 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Dictionary.html), too. Deprecation happens for various reasons like security issues, implementation/design bugs or better alternatives. You can read more about [Deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Deprecated.html)