# Is there a way to use string names as indexes in java arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to use names as indexes in arrays?
like

```
ary["name"]="ABCD";
ary["age"]="20";

System.out.println(ary["name"] + " " + ary["age"]);
```

Comment: no you can't do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create a dictionary in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543457/how-do-you-create-a-dictionary-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead.

> An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate
>   keys; each key can map to at most one value.

In your case, your snippet would be:

```
Map<String,String> ary = new HashMap<String,String>();
ary.put("name","ABCD");
ary.put("age", "20");

System.out.println(ary.get("name") + " " + ary.get("age"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a HashMap

Example:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("hello","hi");
System.out.println(map.get("hello"));
```

output: hi

Answer (score 2):

It'd be a dictionary at that point. From: [How do you create a dictionary in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543457/how-do-you-create-a-dictionary-in-java):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("dog", "type of animal");
System.out.println(map.get("dog"));
```