# Group Dataset into different Sub Datasets based on the value

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, grouping

I want to implement a program on a Dataset consisting of few columns like the following:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|Item_ID    |Product_Name   |Manufacturer_Name  |Product_Description    |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|12345      |Pen            |Cello              |Ball Pen Soft Nib...   |
|12346      |Pencil         |Nataraja           |Pencil HB Extra D...   |
|42345      |Ruler          |Nataraja           |Scale No.1103 15c...   |
|12677      |Sharpener      |Nataraja           |Pencil Shraperner...   |
|12987      |Pen            |Reynolds           |Dot Pen Extra Gr...    |
|44326      |Pen            |Reynolds           |Gel Pen German T...    |
|13456      |Pen            |Cello              |Dot Pen 0.5mm Nib...   |
|19876      |Eraser         |Cello              |Dust free Eraser ...   |
|43246      |Ink Pen        |Hero               |Ink Pen Smooth Ha...   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

and I want to group the Dataset based on the `Manufacturer_Name` like shown below

```
Manufacturer = Cello
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|Item_ID    |Product_Name   |Manufacturer_Name  |Product_Description    |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|12345      |Pen            |Cello              |Ball Pen Soft Nib...   |
|13456      |Pen            |Cello              |Dot Pen 0.5mm Nib...   |
|19876      |Eraser         |Cello              |Dust free Eraser ...   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+

Manufacturer = Nataraja
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|Item_ID    |Product_Name   |Manufacturer_Name  |Product_Description    |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|12346      |Pencil         |Nataraja           |Pencil HB Extra D...   |
|42345      |Ruler          |Nataraja           |Scale No.1103 15c...   |
|12677      |Sharpener      |Nataraja           |Pencil Shraperner...   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+

Manufacturer = Reynolds
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|Item_ID    |Product_Name   |Manufacturer_Name  |Product_Description    |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|12987      |Pen            |Reynolds           |Dot Pen Extra Gr...    |
|44326      |Pen            |Reynolds           |Gel Pen German T...    |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+

Manufacturer = Hero
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|Item_ID    |Product_Name   |Manufacturer_Name  |Product_Description    |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
|43246      |Ink Pen        |Hero               |Ink Pen Smooth Ha...   |
+-----------+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

I tried using the following code which is not yielding good results. Help me improve this program. Here is the code I have used:

```
Dataset<Row> countsBy = src.select("Manufacturer_Name").distinct();
List<Row> lsts = countsBy.collectAsList();
for (Row lst : lsts) {
    String man = lst.toString();
    System.out.println("Records of " + man + " only");
    Dataset<Row> mandataset = src.filter("Manufacturer_Name='" + man + "'");
    mandataset.show();
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the bad results ? Was it slowness or mistakes ?

Comment: I want the subsets of the dataset to be usable outside the iterating section. Since it is declared locally and it is being overwritten every iteration i can not use all the subsets except the subset generated during the last iteration. @AugustinBocken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try to make a map of Datasets, with the key a string (the Manufacturer_Name) and for each iteration, you check the Manufacturer_Name, then you check if it's already in the map(you create it if needed) and finally, you add your row in the good Dataset.

You'll have something like that :

```
Map<string,ArrayList<ShopItem>> dic = new HashMap<string,ArrayList<ShopItem>>();
for(/*...*/)
{
  string Manufacturer_Name = //you get the name
  if(/*the Manufacturer_Name is not in dic*/)
  {
    dic.put(Manufacturer_Name,new ArrayList<ShopItem>());
  }
  dic.get(Manufacturer_Name).Add(/*what you want to add*/);
}
```

You then need a second loop, but only for printing the data.

I hope it will solve your problem !

EDIT : remplaced Dictionnary by Map (sorry) and providing link

[How do you create a dictionary in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13543457/how-do-you-create-a-dictionary-in-java)

EDIT : changed code to match new idea

Comment: Just to clarify few things before implementation. Can a Dictionary be instantiated? and is the methods add and AddValue available in java?

Comment: Maybe only in a library... You're right, I need to check more, or you could implement your own dictionnary ! It's a list of Entry, each entry has an object Key and object Value, that should be enough for your use... But I'll have a look and edit my answer

Comment: Here, I corrected the answer so it's more correct :D

Comment: ` Map<String,Dataset<Row>> dic = new HashMap<String,Dataset<Row>>();
for(Row row : srcrows) {
 String Manufacturer_Name = row.getString(3);
 if(!dic.values().equals(Manufacturer_Name)) {
  dic.put(Manufacturer_Name,new Dataset<Row>());
 }
dic.get(Manufacturer_Name).Add(row); } `
Is this correct?

Comment: **Error one : dic.put(Manufacturer_Name,new Dataset<Row>());
It says "The constructor Dataset<Row>() is undefined"
Error two :  dic.get(Manufacturer_Name).Add(row);
It says "The method Add(Row) is undefined for the type Dataset<Row>"**

I am getting few errors would you please help me solve it?

Comment: Maybe use your own object : a `Item` who would contains 3 properties : *Item_ID*, *Product_Name * and *Product_Description*, then you'll have `HashMap<string,ArrayList<Item>>` and you'll be able to access all Items from a Manufacturer by using `map.get(Manufacturer_Name)` and add new ones with `map.get(Manufacturer_Name).add(itemToAdd)`

Comment: Thank you @AugustinBocken I will implement your thoughts and get back to you. If there is any difficulty I will look forward for your help.

Comment: So, how did your implementation go ? Do you need any more help ?

Comment: Thanks @Augustin It helped me a lot