# Store set of data in java, like python's dict

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I have a set of data that I want to store in a simple variable. Basically a list of fifteen names with location coordinates. In Python I'd create a dict, something like:

`locations = {'Location1': [lat1, lon1], 'Location2': [lat2, lon2], ...}`

So that way I can later call the coordinates by using the location name as key:

`coords = locations['Location1']`

Any equivalent to do this in Java? I basically want to define these locations as a constant in my code.

EDIT after receiving the first very fast replies:

I have now added this:

```
private class coordinates {
    private Long lat;
    private Long lon;
    public Long getLat() {
        return lat;
    }
    public void setLat(Long lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
    public Long getLon() {
        return lon;
    }
    public void setLon(Long lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
}

private final static Map<String, coordinates> LOCATIONS;
```

The last line is of course incomplete; I'm at a loss on how to populate this thing, without using extra temporary variables to access the two setters, resulting in several lines of code for every single set of values.

Comment: A Map containing a custom object with lat and lon fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [**Map in java**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

Like:  `Map<LocationObject, CoordinateObject>`

Where `CoordinateObject has latitude and longitude as attributes`

```
class CoordinateObject {
   //longitude;
   //latitude;
}
```

- [**Related Post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540673/java-equivalent-to-python-dictionaries)

Comment: I was hoping for something that would not add a complete class and a lot more clutter to my program. And how to populate this map?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120283/working-with-latitude-longitude-values-in-java might be helpful then.

Comment: Not applicable in this case; I just need to store the numbers so later I can retrieve them to put markers on a map, no need for any calculations.

Comment: @Wouter in that case using Map with Custom Coordinates class is a way to go.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the correct data structure for this would be a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a more convenient solution by adapting some other answers on StackOverflow, without the trouble of having to create a separate object (and realised I was using the wrong type):

```
private final static Map<String, Double[]> LOCATIONS;
static
{
    LOCATIONS = new Map<String, Double[]>();
    LOCATIONS.put("Central_Western", new Double[] {22.288262, 114.140138});
    LOCATIONS.put("Eastern", new Double[] {22.286078, 114.216957});
}
```

Now I should be able to call `Double[] loc = LOCATIONS["Central_Western"]` and have an array of two numbers.

OK haven't tested it yet... trying such little things is so hard in Java/Android... I so miss Python's console...

Comment: hmm, the thing is what if someone accidentally populates your double array with an extra decimal number ??. java is Object Oriented. and i think you should use a class body for the co-ordinates. :)

Comment: That is impossible as it is a static map, and all data is hard-coded. It is meant to be read-only. And this way it's reasonably clutter-free, and it works. Furthermore no clue on how to easily populate (and read) the data in the map if the value is a custom object.