# Java equivalent of Python dictionary

Tags: java, python, dictionary

Is there a cleaner way for doing this ?

```
public void change(char x)
{
    if(x == 'a')
    {
       return 'b';
    }
    else if(x == 'b')
    {
       return 'a';
    }
    else if(x == 't')
    {
       return 'r';
    }
    else if(x == 'r')
    {
       return 't';
    }
    return 'z';
}
```

I was wondering if there was anything built into Java so that I can swap pairs of characters like a dictionary in Python or is this the best way to do this?

Comment: no it is just switching four characters

Comment: That looks quite simple and readable to me. Shorter is not always better.

Comment: @Rp-, using a Map for this translation would be overkill. Using a two dimensional array might make the code shorter, though.

Comment: @JBNizet: if he a lot of pairs, this would be very tedious

Comment: Yes. I didn't realize that OP needs swaping

Comment: But he doesn't. He always has 2 pairs.

Comment: @TimoGeusch why two dimensions?

Comment: since your case is only about 4 chars, then what you have is the best it can get, just use `switch` instead of`if-else-if` style as mentioned in the answers.

Comment: oh, compile it. bytecodes will be shorter :-) [TGIF]

Comment: very very easy to read :-) return c=='a'?'b':c=='b'?'a':c=='t'?'r':c=='r'?'t':'z';

Comment: @Leo: now do this for the entire alphabet! :D

Comment: @JohannesH. and java uses UNICODE... ;-)

Comment: There are multiple ways of making the source code shorter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540673/java-equivalent-to-python-dictionaries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One might try the following:

```
public char change(char x) {
    final String dictionary = "abtr";
    final String transform = "bart";

    int loc= dictionary.indexOf(x);
    if (loc < 0) {
        return 'z';
    } else {
        return transform.charAt(loc);
    }
}
```

Comment: The "default" value is `"z"` for the author, not `x` itself. I have edited your answer.

Comment: Nice one! I really like that one, it's short, readable and has little overhead. The only drawback is, that Java has to loop over both strings, which might be a performance issue for large replacement maps.

Comment: Well a loop over dictionary, but calculated position for transform.

Comment: Erm... right. So loop only over one string, agreed ;)

Answer (score 12):

Well, it's not making it much shorter, but at least nicer: you could use the `switch` statement instead of your `if-elseif-elseif-...` construct.

```
public char change(char x)
{
    switch (x) {
        case 'a':
            return 'b';
        case 'b':
            return 'a';
        case 't':
            return 'r';
        case 'r':
            return 't';
        default:
            return 'z';
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you had so many pairs ? what if there were new pairs dynamically created at run time ?

Comment: "like dictionary in python" How is this like a Python Dictionary?

Comment: you need a `char` return type there :)

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi No such requirement is specified in the quesiton. If those are true, one should consider jeremyjjbrown's solution.

Comment: I cut "like dictionary in python" out of the question.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown It's not linke one, I agree. But for such simple task, I just don't consider using a Map a solution I'd recommend.

Comment: chains of if / else if tend to obscure what is being done and require longer time for the reader to comprehend what is being done ... and result in sets if jumps that often tend to be longer.

Answer (score 7):

"so that i can swap pairs of characters like dictionary in python"

Just use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). It's just like a Python Dictionary.

```
Map<Character, Character> likeADict = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
likeADict.put('a','b');
likeADict.get('a');
```

You can add and remove values from it at runtime.

Comment: I consider this an overkill. A `HashMap` has quite some overhead, it's not a particulary small structure... for something that simple, I wouldn't wast the memory and lookup time. BUt, agreed: It's the most flexible solution one can do.

Comment: He still needs to check for `null` as return value to return the default (in his case `z`)

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi No, once is enough. Although the put is idempotent so he could put each pair x times.

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown, the pairs he has in his question are symmetric.
if `a` swaps with `b` then `b` should swap with `a`.
so I guess he need to insert the pair and its inverse to work , right ?
in order for this to function as a two way map. or no ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi Sure that's true for any of these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

another cool way is using enum, that way adding new swap value is easy,
just add a mapping into the enum

```
public enum swap{
    a('b'),
    b('a'),
    t('r'),     
    r('t'),
    z('z');

    private swap(char c){
        this.value=c;
    }
    public final char value;
}
```

and the use is:

```
public char change(char x)
{
   swap swapObject = swap.valueOf(Character.toString(x));
   return swapObject.value;
}
```

Comment: This has numerous errors.  (1) Does not compile.  `swap.valueOf(x)` should be `swap.valueOf(Character.toString(x))`.  (2) `change` needs to return something.  (3) The OP's code changed _all_ characters other than a, b, t, r, to z, and this code doesn't do that.  In fact, it doesn't work at all unless `x` is one of those five.  (4) This approach only works when all the characters to be swapped are letters.

Comment: i have changed the code, thanks.i do agree that in case we don't know all the cases we deal with or if we want a default value this approach is not good enough but for this scenario it seems sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map, E.G:

```
public char change(char x) {
    Map <Character, Character> dictionary = new HashMap<Character, Character>() {{
        put('a', 'b');
        put('b', 'a');
        put('t', 'r');
        put('r', 't');
    }};

    if (dictionary.containsKey(x)) {
        return dictionary.get(x);
    } else {
        return 'z';
    }
}
```

However I wouldn't bother if its just a few characters. And I would probably make the dictionary a class field.

Answer (score -1):

The dictionary technic is more flexible but not shorter (like every thing in java). Here is a complete example.

```java
package example;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Dictionary {

    static final TreeMap<Character,Character> myDict = new TreeMap();

    static Character choose(TreeMap<Character,Character> dict, 
                            Character x, Character def) {
        Character result = dict.get(x);
        if (result==null) result = def;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myDict.put('a','b');
        myDict.put('b','a');
        myDict.put('r','t');
        System.out.println(choose(myDict,'a','z'));
        System.out.println(choose(myDict,'b','z'));
        System.out.println(choose(myDict,'r','z'));
        System.out.println(choose(myDict,'X','z'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a TreeMap, which is O(log n), instead of a HashMap, which is O(1), when you don't care about the order of the keys? Also, it should be `new TreeMap<>()`.

Comment: I like TreeMap .. yes HashMap is also OK.. and new TreeMap<> is possible but not nessesary OR?

Comment: @huckfinn "I like" is not a particular good reason for a bad design choice... You do realize that different `Map` (as well as different `List`) implementations have different characteristics for a reason?

Comment: You "like" it? Any good reason? The diamond avoids using raw types and getting unchecked warnings from the compiler.

Comment: Please stop pitching pennies, dimonds and map types.. Is the solution OK?